# SPRING BOOT - Problema peticion POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

No soy experto en JAVA SPRING BOOT, estoy desarrollando un proyecto y mucho del codigo que escribo lo tomo de ideas de la web. El tema es que venia bien con el proyecto hasta que me trabé con lo siguiente...
Necesito hacer POST en un controlador para setear la password de un usuario. Necesito que ese POST esté sin autorizacion, dado que el usuario justamente aun no tiene password. Entonces la idea es que al darlo de alta por un admin, le llegue un mail y el usuario sigue el link y cambia la password. TODO ESTE MECANISMO lo tengo realizado (Angular frontend y java spring boot como backend). El tema es que cuando hago el POST para cambiar la password, me lo rechaza por no tener autorizacion.
Les pongo mi meteodo configure de la SecurityConfig:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v1/api/auth/**")     // <----acá deberia pasar!!!!
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();

    // Add our custom JWT security filter
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

Pero me muestra un mensaje diciendo "Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource" y ese mensaje está en la siguiente clase:

```
package com.adalove.gestor.core.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.adalove.gestor.core.payload.DataResponse;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint 
{

    private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                     HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                     AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());

    DataResponse response = new DataResponse(401, "Usted no está autorizado para ver este recurso", null);
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
    OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, response);
    out.flush();
}
}
```

Por las dudas les dejo el controllador, de manera de mostrar que ahi tampoco hay ninguna restriccion:

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = "auth-controller")
@RequestMapping("v1/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    public ResponseEntity<?> resetPassword(@Valid ResetPasswordRequest resetRequest) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new DataResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Cambio de contraseña", authService.resetPassword(resetRequest)));
    }
}
```

Mi archivo pom.xml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.adalove</groupId>
<artifactId>gestor</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>gestor</name>
<description>Gestor project for CLARO</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For Java 8 Date/Time Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar dado que me esta llevando un monton de tiempo esta problematica.
Gracias de antemano a todos.

Comment: Emiliano, puedes agregar a tu pregunta el contenido de tu archivo POM.xml o build.gradle por favor? Y si quitas Spring Security de tu archivo de dependencias qué pasa?

Comment: @PakLeiChong ahi subí el POM.xml. Que deberia hacer para quitar Spring Security?...de todas maneras (yo no lo copie pero existe) en el controller tengo otra peticion, pero GET, para obtener datos de un usuario, tambien si autorizacion (porque no es un dato sensible) y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Sólo para saber si el problema es una regla o cors de spring security, quita de tu POM las líneas 
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>. Recompila, despliega y prueba el POST.

Comment: @PakLeiChong es que quitando esas lineas me dá error por todos lados del proyecto. Osea, es un proyecto que está avanzado. Todo funcionaba bien, tengo un login y un GET de datos, que van sin autorizacion y funciona todo HASTA que agregué este POST para cambiar la clave

Comment: Ok, veo que tienes un método que se llama **resetPassword**, ese método está expuesto? Tienes alguna forma de probarlo con algún cliente HTTP como insomnia o postman?

Comment: Si, está expuesto...justamente es el que me dice que no tengo autorizacion cuando no deberia necesitarla. Lo he probado tambien desde POSTMAN y ARC y la respuesta es la misma

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94888/discussion-between-pak-lei-chong-and-emiliano-torres).